# Как выборочно вывести данные из JSON в HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть json с курсами валют:

```
"USD\/JPY": {
    "bid": 104.16,
    "ask": 104.167,
    "type": "Forex",
    "code": "USD\/JPY",
    "mid": 104.1635,
    "movement": "down",
    "spread": 0.7
  },
"USD\/CHF": {
    "bid": 0.89134,
    "ask": 0.89139,
    "type": "Forex",
    "code": "USD\/CHF",
    "mid": 0.891365,
    "movement": "up",
    "spread": 0.5
  },
"EUR\/USD": {
    "bid": 1.21273,
    "ask": 1.41278,
    "type": "Forex",
    "code": "EUR\/USD",
    "mid": 1.212755,
    "movement": "down",
    "spread": 0.5
  },
"Silver": {
    "bid": 24.16,
    "ask": 24.19,
    "type": "Metals",
    "code": "Silver",
    "mid": 24.175,
    "movement": "down",
    "spread": 0.03
  },
"Gold": {
    "bid": 1836.5,
    "ask": 1836.77,
    "type": "Metals",
    "code": "Gold",
    "mid": 1836.635,
    "movement": "down",
    "spread": 0.27
  }
```

Вот такой jQuery код выводит списком bid всех валют:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON('js/quotes.json', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      items.push('<li>' + val.bid + '</li>');
    });
    $('<ul/>', {
      'class': 'list',
      html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

А как вывести bid только выбранных валют, например: USD/JPY и EUR/USD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо использования `each` обратиться к объекту по ключу

```
...
var items = [];
items.push('<li>' + data['USD\/JPY'].bid + '</li>');
items.push('<li>' + data['EUR\/USD'].bid + '</li>');
...
```